# Get the highest date with combination of day,month and year

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on a game , where  i have a table called `punishment`  which have following schema

```
CREATE TABLE Punishment
(
  PunishmentId int identity(1,1) not null , 
  PunishmentDay int , 
  PunishmentMonth int , 
  PunishmentYear int ,
  GameId int 
)
```

PunishmentDay ,PunishmentMonth ,PunishmentYear are numbers  which can be either zero or null or any number.

`GameId` can be repeat in this table , means i can get multiple times punishment for the same game.

Now my question is i have to get the `punishmentId` in which user get the  highest punishment.

I have tried following way but not able to get the max record ..

```
SELECT PunishmentId, DATEADD(DD,PunishmentDay,DATEADD(MM,PunishmentMonth,(DATEADD(YY,PunishmentYear,GETDATE()))))

   FROM Punishment
```

Comment: because punishment is not a date . these are numbers .... may be you get 3 days punishment and i will get 2 years punishment .. and punishment start date is also defined latter stage in game.

Comment: Then the max combination would be `MAX(Year * 10000 + Month * 100 + Day)`

Comment: Why not canonicalize all punishments into times in days?  You can use 30-day months and 365-day years without significant inaccuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() instead of a correlated subquery to find the max year/month/day. ROW_NUMBER() will allow you assign an incrementing row number based on an order by clause. You can then select only rows where that rownumber = 1. Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT PunishmentId,PunishmentDay,PunishmentMonth,PunishmentYear, DATEADD(DD,PunishmentDay,DATEADD(MM,PunishmentMonth,(DATEADD(YY,PunishmentYear,GETDATE())))) TotalDays, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GameId ORDER BY PunishmentYear, PunishmentMonth, PunishmentDay DESC) RowNumber
FROM Punishment
WHERE GameId = @GameId 
) OrderedPunishment
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Note: I haven't checked this for syntax, and I based the statement off your statement (pretty much ignored your nested dateadds, maybe there is a better way to do that too). I also only just now noticed your second table name ConvictCases_G... I didn't see that that is supposed to be Punishment.

Comment: THAT IS A COPY PAST MISTAKE . i edited that table name also . that is actually Punishment table. thanks for answer .I will try with rownumber .

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by following sql

```
SELECT PunishmentId,PunishmentDay,PunishmentMonth,PunishmentYear, DATEADD(DD,PunishmentDay,DATEADD(MM,PunishmentMonth,(DATEADD(YY,PunishmentYear,GETDATE()))))

FROM Punishment

WHERE GameId=@GameId  and 
DATEADD(DD,PunishmentDay,DATEADD(MM,PunishmentMonth,(DATEADD(YY,PunishmentYear,GETDATE())))) 
= (SELECT MAX(DATEADD(DD,PunishmentDay,DATEADD(MM,PunishmentMonth,(DATEADD(YY,PunishmentYear,GETDATE())))))   FROM Punishment where GameId=@GameId)
```

but still waiting  if there any better solution can be done ..

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT   TOP 1 PunishmentId
FROM    
(
SELECT  TOP 100 PERCENT
        PunishmentId ,
        SUM(PunishmentDay + PunishmentMonth*30 + PunishmentYear*360) AS MaxPunishment
FROM    @p
GROUP   BY  PunishmentId
ORDER   BY  SUM(PunishmentDay + PunishmentMonth*30 + PunishmentYear*360) DESC 
)
AS X
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
    PunishmentId,PunishmentDay,PunishmentMonth,PunishmentYear, 
    DATEADD(DD,PunishmentDay,DATEADD(MM,PunishmentMonth,(DATEADD(YY,PunishmentYear,GETDATE())))) AS PunishmentEndDate
FROM Punishment
WHERE GameId=@GameId
ORDER BY PunishmentEndDate DESC
```